# OpenCV: arcLength assert fails with cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I tried to calculate contour perimeter using `arcLength`. The contour is read from the file into `Mat` which is a black and white picture of contour only.
However, when I pass this `Mat` into function it throws an error:

```
Assertion failed (curve.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (curve.depth() == CV_32F || curve.depth() == CV_32S)) in arcLength
```

I have figured out that the actual cause is that `curve.checkVector(2)` returns -1. Although I have read the documentation about this method I still do not understand how to fix this error.
Here is the test image with corner points (1,1), (1,21), (21,21), (21,1)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contour should be (from [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#arclength)):

> Input vector of 2D points, stored in std::vector or Mat.

not a b/w image.

You can compute the perimeter is different ways. The most robust is to use `findContours` to find external contours only (`RETR_EXTERNAL`), and call `arcLength` on that contour.

A few examples:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Method 1: length of unsorted points
    // NOTE: doesn't work!

    vector<Point> points;
    findNonZero(img, points);
    double len1 = arcLength(points, true);
    // 848.78

    // Method 2: length of the external contour

    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(img.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE); // Retrieve only external contour
    double len2 = arcLength(contours[0], true);
    // 80



    // Method 3: length of convex hull of contour
    // NOTE: convex hull based methods work reliably only for convex shapes.

    vector<Point> hull1;
    convexHull(contours[0], hull1);
    double len3 = arcLength(hull1, true);
    // 80

    // Method 4: length of convex hull of unsorted points
    // NOTE: convex hull based methods work reliably only for convex shapes.

    vector<Point> hull2;
    convexHull(points, hull2);
    double len4 = arcLength(hull2, true);
    // 80


    // Method 5: number of points in the contour
    // NOTE: this will simply count the number of points in the contour.
    // It works only if: 
    //     1) findContours was used with option CHAIN_APPROX_NONE.
    //     2) the contours is thin (has thickness of 1 pixel).

    double len5 = contours[0].size(); 
    // 80

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This removes the assertion error, but the result is incorrect. I have created a square contour, each side is equal to 20 and the answer I got is 848.784, it should be 80, though.
I also do not understand how else points can be stored in Mat.

Comment: I have just looked into the points order and it seems that they need to be sorted. I will get back with the result later

Comment: Great! I must say I thought about the find contours but did not choose the right configuration constant.
**There is also one more important point.** Convex will **not always** work correctly as one may have a more complex contour (I have such images as well). I am also not quite sure if the last method 5 will work for other examples, e.g. triangle.
So I suggest adding a comment to the answer from your side and I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Anjenson I assumed you only had images like the one you posted. In general not every method will work good, as you said. So added a few comments to clarify this. Let me know if it's clearer now.